# Python "maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison" with variable arguments. Works fine with lists, however

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, recursion, tuples

I have the following function:

```
def lst(*l):
  if l==():return None
  else: return cons(l[0],lst(l[1:]))
```

When I run it, I get "maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison". Curiously, when I add a warper which converts the parameter tuple into a list, everything works just fine:

```
def lst(*l):
  return _lst(list(l))

def _lst(l):
  if l==[]:return None
  else: return (l[0],_lst(l[1:]))

>>> lst(1,2)
(1, (2, None))
```

What is the problem and how to deal with this strange behavior?

Comment: Can you post the code that actually works, too?

Comment: Replace `if l==():return None` with `if not l: return None`. Also, what does `cons` do? You might be able to replace this with `reduce`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, @IceArdor. `cons` is a constructor like that: `def __init__(self,car,cdr):self.car=car;self.cdr=cdr`. I tried to replace the recursion with `reduce`, but something went wrong (seems like `reduce` works "wrong" direction) and I have absolutely no idea how to get it the right way. As long as i have a working code, thanks to Samy Arous, I wish not to make it broken. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are missing a * when passing the parameters again to the function

```
def lst(*l):
  if l==():return None
  else: return cons(l[0],lst(*l[1:]))
```

You are passing the empty tuple as a first positional parameter which means that in the next recursion **l** is actually equal to **((),)** (a tuple containing one empty tuple) when it should be **()**